# SVG Stroke Not Appearing When Converting to Icon Font

Tags: svg, fonts

### Goal

I am trying to create an SVG icon to add to an icon font file.

[image]

### Progress

I have created an SVG icon, which appears perfectly inline and as an `img`

### Problem

When I upload it to add to my icon font, using both Icomoon and Fontastic, all fills appear, but all strokes are missing. I've run the code through the W3C validator and gotten no issues, and I'm wondering if icon fonts have more rules that plain SVG does have?

[image]

### Code

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="51" height="51" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <polygon points="0,5.5 31,0 31,50 0,44" />
  <ellipse cx="15" cy="25" rx="7.5" ry="11" fill="transparent" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" />
  <path d="M31 10.5 L48.5 10.5 L49 11 L50 12.5 L35 23 L31 20" stroke-width="2" fill="white" stroke="black" />
  <path d="M52 12 L35 23 L31 20 L31 24 L35 27 L50 16.5" fill="black" />
  <path d="M31 24 L35 27 L50 16.5 L50 35 L49.5 37 L47.5 37.5 L31 37.5" stroke-width="2" fill="white" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Two of the three paths are "white" and the one that isn't has no stroke value or width ... may be setting to white.

Comment: The path with no fill or stroke has the fill automatically set to black. It's the only one that is appearing, of the three paths. The other two paths are appearing as white, but their stroke's aren't appearing.

Comment: But what I see is that the black outer border is missing ... is that actuakky part of the background with white on top of it?

Comment: I see with the stroke and stroke-width surrounding the fill, I got a bit lost.  Could there be CSS rules over-riding (!important or something like that) inside the tools you are using to iconize them?  Maybe they are there, but not visible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Iconmoon ...

- **Strokes get ignored by the app**. You can convert them to fills.
- Unite/combine your fills.
- All colors are interpreted as black. Instead of using the white color for making holes, subtract the foreground shape from the background shape.

These seem to be pretty strict rules you will have to follow.

Source ... https://icomoon.io/docs.html

Comment: That does match exactly what is happening, bah. I thought that since it was happening in multiple apps it might be something with the SVG itself.

Comment: Sorry ... it goes that way sometimes.  You saw I was checking the SVG for issues; I was hoping it was in the SVG, as well.  Glad I could help.

Comment: I've messaged Fontastic to request adding an explanation about this limitation, since at least Icomoon does explain it if you go into the docs. On the other hand, I can't be too unhappy given they are both free services which overall do a really great job.

Comment: We just had another case, where a transparent hole was left in the svg, covering part of the glyph and was rendered white while generating at fontastic